# How can I sort latest upload file using DirectoryIterator

Tags: php

Actually I'm looking for help on my script( I accept any modification on my script ) which i need to sort the result from latest date to show 1st. Below is the script which I currently use :

```
<?php
  function listFolderFiles($dir){
    echo '<ol>';
    $dirsort = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach ($dirsort as $fileInfo) {
    if (!$fileInfo->isDot()) {
      if($fileInfo->getExtension() === 'jpg' && date("Y",$fileInfo->getMTime()) === '2016')
      echo '<div>Date Upload : '.date("Y-m-d",$fileInfo->getMTime()).' <br/></div>';
      if ($fileInfo->isDir()) { listFolderFiles($fileInfo->getPathname()); }
      }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
  }

listFolderFiles('images');
?>
```

This output currently like this :

> Date Upload : 2016-10-25
>   Date Upload : 2016-10-25
>   Date
>   Upload : 2016-10-25
>   Date Upload : 2016-10-25
>   Date Upload :
>   2016-10-25
>   Date Upload : 2016-10-25
>   Date Upload :
>   2016-10-25
>   Date Upload : 2016-10-25
>   Date Upload :
>   2016-10-26

But I want to show 2016-10-26 first.. hope anyone can help..

Comment: Might not be the best, but try: foreach(array_reverse($array) as $value)

Comment: thanks Mitch, i finally found the other way to do that.. 
referring to Ghost answer in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601631/sort-files-by-date-latest-at-top-using-recursivedirectoryiterator

i missed this part when do coding " **you could gather the results first, get the time then sort that then present it** " - Thanks to **Ghost**